# UIButton with two titles one on left another on right

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a situation where a button title has two parts with different strings, and need to display one on the right and one on the left. Text will change dynamically every time based on response. I have to place this button in a tableview cell. Attaching an image below for reference.

[image]

The requirement is as follows:

[image].

But I managed to do the following:

[image]

I am unable to place text on two different sides of a button.

Comment: So do that. What's the problem?

Comment: I have attached image above please go through it once..How to set title on two different sides? text will change dynamically every time.

Comment: Just add two UILabels, set their positions and then add a UIButton without text that covers them both.

Comment: Please ask a _question_. Don't tell us your "situation". This is easy to do. What's the hard part for you? What have you tried? What happened when you did?

Comment: Create a label on top of the button and attached to the left margin of the button either you can use “NSAttributedString” for different string button title.

Comment: @matt my English might be poor, now I edited my question. if possible please go though once. I posted an image what I managed to do and what is required. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @PAC any other way to customise UIButton or doing it through storyboard?

Comment: @PavanKumar mentioned above is the one of the simple way,  you can do it through storyboard also.

Comment: @PAC  Please let me know, How it can be done with storyboard or any other customisation?

Comment: Number  string(1.07) has to be in label which you have to create and place it on top of button right side.

Comment: You should provide a sample of your code, what have you done so far ?

Comment: @DamienBannerot, due to length code I can't place here, But I have problem with that button placing title on it.....like showed in image all are UITableviewCells and UIButton is placed on it.

Comment: You probably should create a custom UIButton class (inheriting from UIButton), and place the labels inside as you want. I assume you are currently only using button's title ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for you may be to place a UILabel on the left and anchor it to the left with a constraint, then place a UILabel on the right, and anchor it to the right with a constraint. - this is mentioned in the comments by @Alejandro Iván.

I would then choose a set value for the right label width and set that label. Add a constraint from the left label to the right label, so it will dynamically fill as much space as is available.

Last I would place a clear, no text button with the border on top, wrapping both labels. You can then confidently change the left label content and know that it will be encompassed in the button border.

Image attached to help you see what I'm saying although I've left the "button" text and added coloration to demonstrate.

[image]